# KeyError exception during twisted AMP test

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, python-mock

I'm trying to make a simple integration test using Twisted and I found an error which I can't handle.

The only purpose of the test is to make an AMP call using callremote and expect returns a true. The code of this test is a simplification of the development code, which works fine.

The AMP call is described in this lines.

```
class SendMsg(amp.Command):

    arguments = [('sMsg', amp.String()),('iTimestamp', amp.Integer())]
    response = [('bResult', amp.Boolean())]
    errors = {SlotErrorNotification: 'SLOT_ERROR_NOTIFICATION'}
```

I have also described the protocol in a class called SATNETServer

```
class SATNETServer(amp.AMP):

    def vSendMsg(self, sMsg, iTimestamp):
        return {'bResult': True}
    SendMsg.responder(vSendMsg)
```

To establish communication I have an object that simulates transport.

```
class FakeTransport(object):

    def write(self, data):
        self.peer.dataReceived(data)

    def loseConnection(self):
        pass

    def getPeer(self):
        pass

    def getHost(self):
        pass
```

Class test responsible.

```
class ClientToServerTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def mock_processframe(self, AMP_self, frame):

        CONNECTION_INFO = {}
        gsi = object

        clientprotocol = ClientProtocol(CONNECTION_INFO, gsi)
        clientprotocol.callRemote = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=self.mock_callremote)
    clientprotocol._processframe(frame)


def mock_callremote(self, SendMsg, sMsg, iTimestamp):
    try:
        self.amp.callRemote(SendMsg, sMsg='hola', iTimestamp=misc.get_utc_timestamp())
    except Exception as e:
        log.err(e)

def setUp(self):       
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    log.msg("")

    server = SATNETServer()
    self.amp = AMP()

    server.makeConnection(FakeTransport())
    self.amp.makeConnection(FakeTransport())

    server.transport.peer = self.amp
    self.amp.transport.peer = server

    return True

def test_AMPPresentCorrectFrame(self):
    frame = 'Frame'
    CONNECTION_INFO = {}
    GS = 'Vigo'

    self.amp._processframe = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=self.mock_processframe)

    gsi = GroundStationInterface(CONNECTION_INFO, GS, self.amp)._manageFrame(frame)
```

The error I get when I run the above code is as follows.

```
2015-11-16 18:34:57+0100 [-] Amp server or network failure unhandled by client application.  Dropping connection!  To avoid, add errbacks to ALL remote commands!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 978, in ampBoxReceived
    self._commandReceived(box)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 957, in _commandReceived
    deferred.addCallback(self._safeEmit)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 317, in addCallback
    callbackKeywords=kw)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 306, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 989, in _safeEmit
    aBox._sendTo(self.boxSender)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 642, in _sendTo
    proto.sendBox(self)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 2218, in sendBox
    self.transport.write(box.serialize())
  File "test_clientToServer.py", line 83, in write
    self.peer.dataReceived(data)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 2243, in dataReceived
    return Int16StringReceiver.dataReceived(self, data)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 765, in dataReceived
    self.stringReceived(packet)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 877, in stringReceived
    self.state = statehandler(string)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 2296, in proto_key
    self.boxReceiver.ampBoxReceived(self._currentBox)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 974, in ampBoxReceived
    self._answerReceived(box)
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/generic-client/.venv_test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/amp.py", line 904, in _answerReceived
    question = self._outstandingRequests.pop(box[ANSWER])
exceptions.KeyError: '1'
```

I searched for documentation and I could not find anything that I clarify what could happen. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're trying to get box[1], which is apparently not a thing.

Comment: As I think, "Box" is used for message reception not for message sending. It's is right?

Comment: This code is missing definitions for `GroundStationInterface`, `SlotErrorNotification`, `ClientProtocol`, etc.  Please convert it into an http://sscce.org/.  You might be interested in the `proto_helpers` module in Twisted - https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.test.proto_helpers.html - which will help you avoid using MagicMock.  (See also https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6435 )

Comment: I ignored the imports of GroundStationInterface,  SlotErrorNotification, ClientProtocol and some more. I don't know how to further reduce the code when I don't know where it comes from failure. I'll see if I can find other examples of reference.